# Domain blocked by ISP

Tags: domain, isp, block

ISPs blocked my domain in one country. It redirects to an IP address that the ISP uses to block access to sites it blocks. (https://ispipaddress:8080/mydomain.com)

The URL cannot be accessed directly, but it can be accessed when clicked from Google results or when redirected from somewhere (such as url shortening sites). or if they add https to the beginning of the URL in direct access. (**Some visitors only**)

How can my visitors reach my site without using a VPN or proxy? What should I do?

Comment: Ask the ISP why they blocked it and what the appeal process is.

Comment: I don't wonder why. I'm looking for a solution and ISP won't fix it.

Comment: The solution is to get the ISP to fix it. Or put them out of business.

Answer (score 3):

If a network issue is interfering with connections to your site when accessed in plaintext HTTP, but not doing so when accessed via HTTPs, **simply making sure that all your visitors access your site via HTTPs should be sufficient**.

The currently only method to do that is become eligible and submit to the **HSTS preload list** and then wait for browser vendors to include your site. This process is not immediately effective, and only affects some browsers (but most of the currently relevant ones). After your domain name is shipped, all visitors will connect to your server securely, regardless of whether they are forwarded or manually typing the name.

This treats the symptom. To treat the actual problem, you will have to provide details about why that particular ISP is causing trouble:

- unintentionally breaking things by running broken software?
- wilfully interfering because government authorities told them so?
- wilfully interfering because a court order told them so?

The domain name, the ISP and the affected jurisdictions/regions would likely pinpoint the issue and help decide which resolution methods may be appropriate, even if the ISP is unresponsive/uncooperative.

Comment: The default scheme - with or without preloading - is expected to become http**s** [soon](https://blog.chromium.org/2021/03/a-safer-default-for-navigation-https.html)